# Perform analysis on an array/collection type

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle Pl/SQL if i have an array or collection type filled with numbers how can i get an average, stddev or the result of any other mathematical operation?

I can figure out a horrible way of doing average by looping though and storing the total, count and average so far but is there somthing like

avg:=my_collection.avg

std:=my_collection.stddev

?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the collection into a TABLE:

```
select *
from TABLE ( cast( some_data as mytableType ) )
```

And then use normal analytical functions.